# Why does the number of fragments vary significantly from one system to the other despite no changes in source code?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, gpu, fragment-shader

I have implemented a shader that counts how many fragments it generates.

I have noticed that, without changing the code, the number of counted generated fragments is different in different machines.

It's consistent in one machine (always the same value), but distinctly different on different computers.

The monitors have the same resolution but the graphic cards are different. My expectation is, that if the geometry, shaders, C++ code, viewport dimensions and monitor are the same, the number of fragments should also be the same, but it seems I am wrong, why would that be?

EDIT:
It was requested I add the MVC example. I honestly don't think it's actually relevant to the question since this is not behaviour that would be specific to my code but a property of GPUs none the less:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 430

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;  // (x,y,z) coordinates of a vertex
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;      // normal to the vertex
layout(location = 2) in vec2 uv;        // texture coordinates

out vec3 v_pos;
out vec3 v_norm;
out vec2 v_uv;

uniform mat4 model_m = mat4(1); // model matrix
uniform mat4 view_m = mat4(1);  // view matrix
uniform mat4 proj_m = mat4(1);  // perspective projection matrix

void main()
{
    v_pos = vec3(model_m*vec4(position,1));
    v_norm = vec3(model_m*vec4(normal,1.0));
    v_uv = uv;

    gl_Position = proj_m*view_m*vec4(v_pos, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 430

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position; // (x,y,z) coordinates of a vertex

out vec3 v_pos;

uniform mat4 model_m = mat4(1); // model matrix

void main()
{
    v_pos = vec3(model_m*vec4(position,1));
}
```

C++:

```
    //Binding the buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &ssbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo);
    glObjectLabel(GL_BUFFER, ssbo, -1, "\"SSBO\"");
    GLint zero = 0;
    glBufferStorage(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(GLint), &zero,
        GL_MAP_READ_BIT | GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ssbo);
GLuint *counter;
void render()
{
    glClearColor(0,0.5,0.5,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(counter);
    mesh->draw();
    glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);
    GLint z2;
    glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLint), &z2);
    cout << "Fragments: " << z2 << endl;
    GLint zero=0;
    glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLint), &zero);endl;

}
```

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @SidS I don't see the need for it, but I have added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is not a pixel-accurate API. As such, implementations can implement rasterization in slightly different ways, or provide different numeric precision, which generate different numbers of fragments.

Also, if you're rendering an actual scene rather than just a full-screen quad, there can be other effects. For example, let's say you have two triangles in a rendering command, and one of them is closer than the other. On some piece of hardware, the closer triangle does its full read/modify/write pass on the depth buffer before the farther triangle gets rasterized at all. If [early depth tests are on](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test), then none of the fragment shaders for fragments from the farther triangle gets produced.

But what if fragments from both triangles get processed at the same time? That could happen, and what causes that will depend on the hardware (and the distance between the triangles in the rendering command). For some pixels, the farther triangle will get some of its fragments counted as well as the nearer one.

This is also why it is important to [turn *on* early fragment tests](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test#Explicit_specification) if you're using image load/store operations in tandem with depth tests.

Comment: For my current use case, turning that feature on would actually be detrimental as depth has nothing to do with which fragment should be prioritized (for the voxelization algorithm). Also the geometry and camera position are identical in all cases. Since I was testing that the number of fragments be consistent I made sure nothing was modified.

Comment: @Makogan: "*Also the geometry and camera position are identical in all cases.*" That means precisely nothing as far as numeric precision and rasterization differences are concerned. Again, OpenGL is not a pixel-accurate API. There are no guarantees that every implementation will produce binary-identical results.

Comment: @Makogan: "*For my current use case, turning that feature on would actually be detrimental as depth has nothing to do with which fragment should be prioritized (for the voxelization algorithm).*" So... did you turn it *off*? Because if you didn't, it's dealer's choice. And since the "dealer" believes that your program will be faster with early-depth tests on, they probably are.

Comment: I was just clarifying that the difference in  generated fragments is not caused by the geometry changing in across systems or across time (the number of generated fragments is cosnistent across time)

Comment: Yes, depth testing, back face culling and blending have all been disabled